# js can not call function name right

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to make one javascript function, but I cannot call my function name right when i click on it(`show_more_in_month_0/1/2`).

this is my code

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($data as $row){
    echo '<td><span class="glyphicon-plus show_more_in_mont_'.$i.'"></span><span class="glyphicon-minus_'.$i.'"></span></td>';
    echo '<td>'; 
    echo $row[0];
    echo '</td><td>;
    echo $row[1];
    echo '</td><td>';
    echo $row[2];
    echo '</td><tr>'; 
    $i ++;
}
```

And this is my script, i just want alert my class name after i call right function name

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".show_more_in_mont_'.$i.'.").click(function(){
        alert(show_more_in_mont_'.$i.');
    });
});
```

Comment: `.show_more_in_month_` or `.show_more_in_mont_`? Also, the quoting in the `$()` and `alert()` calls look a bit wonky.

Comment: You have a bunch of broken strings missing quotes, you're using php variables in your JavaScript, which is simply not possible like that, and you'll finish counting `$i` before the script even gets to the JS part.

Comment: yes i can not write in right string :(

Comment: Where does your JS script get its values for $i? You should match on a class common to all and then extract the ID value from the clicked item.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong -- $i i suppose its your PHP variable ? well you shouldnt have those in your JS..

Just add as javascript one global class such "show-more-container" and use it to show whatever you want to show

```
$( document ).ready(function() {   
    $(".show-more-container").click( function() {
        var elementId = $(this).data('id');
        alert ('show_more_in_mont_'+elementId);
    });       
});
```

Now your html should look like

```
<div data-id="<?= $i ?>" class="show-more-container">
</div>
```

Hope this make sense to you :)

EDIT:

If you want to go far -- and call that as a function then do as follow:

```
window['my_fn_name_as_string'+appendId]()
```

for this to work the function should be on a Global scope -- on Body or Head and not inside Jquery! if you want to add it to jQuery then make sure you use:

```
$.function() {
    window.my_fn_name_as_string_div = function() { }
}
```

EXAMPLE:
     http://jsfiddle.net/7d23y99b/1/

Comment: I can not give my class name with it ?

Comment: What you mean class name ? you can give anything you want : ) if i were you i would add the part of the fn i would want to call within a DATA attr -- such data-class="part_of_function" and append this data within the click event after that you can grab all data information using $.data() -- Check docs here: http://api.jquery.com/data/